# Setting up Stormcrawler and ElasticSearch to crawl our website html file and pdf documents

Tags: html, elasticsearch, pdf, stormcrawler

We are using StormCrawler and ElasticSearch to crawl our website. We followed the documentation for using ElasticSearch with StormCrawler. When we search in Kibana we do get back html files results but not the pdf files content or links.  How do we setup Stormcrawler to crawl and store in Elastic our website html and pdf files content.  What configuration changes do we need to make. Does this have something to do with outlinks settings? Is there documentation that tell us how to setup StormCrawler and ElasticSearch to crawl html and pdf documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking at the 'content' index in Kibana but should also look at the 'status' index, the latter should contain PDF docs. A quick look at the logs would have also told you that the PDFs are getting fetched but that the parser is skipping them. The status index contains an ERROR status and a message mentioning 'content-type checking'.

So, how do you fix it? Just add the Tika module as a Maven dependency and follow the steps on its [README](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/tika/README.md), this way the PDF docs will get redirected to the Tika Parsing Bolt which is able to extract text and metadata from them. They should then be indexed correctly into the 'content' index.

Comment: Yes, thanks the status index does contain those errors. Once I follow the read me will the pdf be searchable in the Status index?  I am new to all these tools. Does that mean to search for html data I search the content index and for pdf type I search in the status index?

Comment: no, the pdf will be in the content index as I indicated earlier. Maybe have a look at the video tutorial if you haven't done so already -> https://youtu.be/8kpJLPdhvLw

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean to confuse things, we have successfully set up StormCrawler and ElasticSearch and the html files are successfully being parsed into the content index.  The problem like you stated is the pdfs are being parsed and were getting errors in the status index.  I read the Tika module, readme instructions you reference above but I’m not clear on what configuration file setting updates need to be made or added. Where does the jsoup.treat.non.html.as.error: change need to be made and where does the setbolt setting need to be added.  Sorry, new to the linux and not a java programmer.

Comment: As you've seen in the tutorial (https://youtu.be/8kpJLPdhvLw?t=1183) the config is in crawler-conf.yaml and the topology is defined in the .flux file

Comment: Hi Julien, I looked at the video , added the the jsoup.treat.non.html.as.error: false  to the crawler-conf.yaml file.  Added tika dependency to the pom.xml.  I don't understand the rest of the READ ME instructions. The next step is to use a RedirectionBolt etc... I'm I supposed to put the  builder.setBolt("jsoup", new JSoupParserBolt()).localOrShuffleGrouping(
          "sitemap");  etc..   lines of code in the es-crawler.flux files.  We are totally new to this, the html parsing works perfectly getting the pdf working is key. We don't know the step by step configuration syntax needed.

Comment: Looking in the es-crawler.flux file I didn't see any similar lines of configuration or code that looks like the README setbolt lines code. Is there a way I can send you our configuration files?  Although our configuration files are exactly like the files here. https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external/elasticsearch  It looks like to us per the instructions the only 3 files needing to be updated is the pom.xml,es-crawler.flux and the crawler-conf.yaml. Thanks any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Rlcheatham ah, sorry I overlooked that the instructions were given for topologies defined in Java code, not in Flux. I pasted a Flux topo which should be similar to yours but with Tika for non HTML pages -> https://gist.github.com/jnioche/3f09c2e3f7da845181b733253bc806f1
If you difff it against your version, you should see the equivalent of the instructions on the README. Let me know how it goes

Comment: https://twitter.com/digitalpebble/status/1364133893700530178

Comment: Thank you for the example that helped a lot. I will close this issue and post another question.  I run the topology and got errors,  error like. 
Exception in thread "main" Cannot create property=streams for JavaBean=org.apache.storm.flux.model.TopologyDef@65e98b1c
in 'string', line 1, column 1:
    name: "crawler"
    ^
Cannot create property=grouping for JavaBean=org.apache.storm.flux.model.StreamDef@1ff4931d
in 'string', line 94, column 5:
      - from: "shunt"
        ^
Cannot create property=streamid for JavaBean=org.apache.storm.flux.model.GroupingDef@710f4dc7   etc...